# Rewrite rules for assets directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do the following:

1. Redirect `https://www.example.com/website` to `https://www.example.com/website2020`
2. Get images to show up on my page. When viewing the page, I have broken images that are not showing up as it is looking for images located: `https://www.example.com/website/assets/`

The images have moved to `https://www.example.com/website2020/assets/`

```
   ### Redirect seems to be working
   RedirectMatch 302   (?i)^/website(/.*)?$ /website2020 
   ### Rewrite rule not working
   RewriteRule  ^/website/assets(/.*)?$  /website2020/assets
```

How would I rewrite so that it shows the images when viewing the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

Just try a simple rule like this:

```
RedirectMatch 302 (?i)^/website(/.*)?$ /website2020$1
```

`$1` is back-reference of capture group #1 i.e.`(/.*)`.

Comment: Make sure you test in a new browser to avoid old cache.

Comment: I tried it in a new browser and the thumbnail image appears on the browser.  However, when I inspect the element in the developer tools, it still has the <a href="https://www.mycompany.com/website/assets">. When I right click and copy link address and paste it into the browser it works. Is there a way to also when inspecting the code to have the a href tag = <a href="https://www.mycompany.com/website2020/assets">

Comment: @MoxieC To see the desired URL when "inspecting the code" then you have no choice but to change the HTML source code.

Comment: @MoxieC: It appears you're still using a cached page. Test in Chrome dev tool with **caching disabled** option and check in Network tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.
chrome://flags/#enable-force-dark

Answer (score 0):

Answering in reverse...

> 2. Get images to show up on my page. When viewing the page, I have broken images that are not showing up as it is looking for images located: `https://www.example.com/website/assets/`

If the images have moved (internally) and you are not able to modify your HTML source code then you should consider implementing an internal rewrite for your assets, not an external redirect. An external redirect will be hopelessly inefficient, particularly if you have many images. (An external redirect can still be used for the main URL - see below.)

> ```
> ### Rewrite rule not working
> RewriteRule  ^/website/assets(/.*)?$  /website2020/assets
> ```

In `.htaccess` the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash. You are also failing to copy the requested "asset" (image). If this only applies to *images* (as you suggest) then consider only matching images.

For example, try this at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Internally rewrite assets
RewriteRule  ^website/assets(/.*)?$  /website2020/assets$1 [L]
```

The `L` flag is required if you have other mod_rewrite directives later in the file.

> 1. Redirect `https://www.example.com/website` to `https://www.example.com/website2020`

If you have implemented an internal rewrite as above then you should implement the redirect using mod_rewrite, not a mod_alias `RedirectMatch` (which executes later).

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect everything, except assets
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/website/assets
RewriteRule ^website(/.*)?$ /website2020$1 [R=302,L]

# Internally rewrite assets
RewriteRule  ^website/assets(/.*)?$  /website2020/assets$1 [L]
```

Comment: Is there any real need of 2 rules? Just `RewriteRule ^website(/.*)?$ /website2020$1 [R=302,L]` will redirect `/website/assets/.*` as well.

Comment: @anubhava Ordinarily no, and a single redirect (as you suggest) does "work". However, it seems from comments that the old URLs to these images ("thumbnails") are still present in the HTML source. If there are many "thumbnails" then a plethora of external redirects on each request would not be desirable. So, IF the URLs to these images in the HTML source cannot be updated then an internal rewrite for these assets instead would be preferable (so in effect the assets haven't actually moved). But otherwise, changing the URLs in the HTML and implementing a single redirect would be the best option.